# problem with casting float -> double in C when fread

Tags: c++, c, file-io

I have a problem with casting from float to double when fread;

```
fread(doublePointer,sizeofFloat,500,f);
```

if i change  double pointer to float pointer, it works just fine. 
However,i need it to be double pointer for laster on, and i thought when i write from small data type (float)to bigger data type(double)'s memory, it should be fine. but it turns out it doesnt work as i expected. 
what is wrong with it, and how do i solve this problem.

i know i can solve it by converting it one by one. but i have a huge amount of data. and i dont wanna extra 9000000+ round of converting.. that would be very expensive. and is there any trick i can solve it?

is there any c++/c tricks

thanks

Comment: You're reading the binary representation of floats directly into the memory of a double, that's not the same as casting a float to a double.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you write float-formatted data into a double, you're only going to get garbage as a result. Sure, you won't overflow your buffer, but that's not the only problem - it's still going to be finding two floats where it expects a double. You need to read it as a float, then convert - casting (even implicitly) in this manner lets the compiler know that the data was originally a float and needs to be converted:

```
float temp[500];
int i;

fread(temp, sizeof(temp[0]), 500, f);
for (i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    doublePointer[i] = temp[i];
```

Comment: i know i can solve it in this way. but i have a huge amount of data. and i do 500 per fread. i dont wanna do another iteration of 500 for each 500 fread...

Comment: The conversion has to be done at some level. float and double just flat out don't store their bits in the same format.

Comment: @grey, Is that iteration of 500 an actual problem, or a theoretical problem ? I'd deal with real problems first (reading the values correctly seems more important and real in this case)

Comment: In addition to the fact that the conversion has to happen somewhere, remember that chances are that the time will be dominated by the file input, not the conversion loop.

Comment: if it is just 500 iterations, i am fine with it. but it would be more than 9000000+ iterations of conversion

Comment: The conversion should be vastly faster than the file read is if done properly.  Implement it, instrument it, measure where the bottlenecks are, *then* worry about performance.

Comment: @Grey, you don't need to do the conversion all in one shot, if that's what you mean. You can read in a few hundred floats, convert them, then load the next few hundred, etc etc.

Comment: seems my plotting tool can also take *float as input. thanks guys. but if there is a trick to do it, let me know.
:) 
thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Suppose for example a float is 4 bytes on your computer.  If you read 500 floats then you read 2000 bytes, one float per float and the result is correct.

Suppose for example a double is 8 bytes on your computer.  If you read 500 floats then you read 2000 bytes, but you're reading them into 250 doubles, 2 floats per double, and the result is nonsense.

If your file has 500 floats you have to read 500 floats.  Cast each float value to a double value.  You can convert each numeric value that way.

When you abuse a pointer, pretending that the pointer points to a type of data that it doesn't really point to, then you're not converting each numeric value, you're preserving nonsense as nonsense.

Edit:  You added to your question "and i dont wanna extra 9000000+ round of converting.. that would be very expensive. and is there any trick i can solve it?"  The answer is yes, you can use a trick of keeping your floats as floats.  If you don't want to convert to doubles then don't convert to doubles, just keep your floats as floats.

Comment: +1 for trick of storing them in the right format in the first place :)

Answer (score 1):

9000000 conversions from float to double is nothing.  `fread` into a `float` array, then convert that into a `double` array.

Benchmark this code scientifically, don't guess about where the slowdowns might be.

If you're bottlenecked on the conversion, write a unrolled, vectorized conversion loop, or use one from a commercial vector library.

If it's still too slow, tile your reads so you read in your float data in batches of a few pages that fit in L1 cache, then convert those to double, then read the next few pages and convert those to double, etc.

If it's *still* too slow, investigate loading your data lazily so only the parts that are needed get loaded, and only when they are used.

A modern x86 core is capable of doing two `float->double` conversions per cycle in a hand-tuned vectorized loop; at 2GHz, that's 4 billion conversions per second per core.  9 million conversions is small change -- my *laptop* does it in less than 1 millisecond.

---

Alternatively, just convert the whole dataset to double once, and read it in that way from now on.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at this from a different perspective. If the data is stored as `float`, then that is all the precision it will ever have. There is no point in converting to `double` until the rules of floating point arithmetic require it.

So I would allocate a buffer for the 500 (or whatever) `float`s, and read them from the data file with one suitable call to `fread()`:

```
float *databuffer;
//...
databuffer = malloc(500 * sizeof(float));
fread(databuffer, sizeof(Float), 500, f);
```

Later, use the data in whatever math it needs to participate in. It will be promoted to `double` if required. Don't forget to eventually free the buffer after it is no longer needed.

If your results really do have all the precision of a `double`, then use a fresh buffer of `double`s to hold them. However, if they are to be written back to file as `float`, then you will eventually need to put them into a buffer of `float`s.

Note that reading and writing files for interchange often needs to be considered a separate problem from efficient storage and usage of data in memory. It is often necessary to read a file and process each individual value in some way. For example, a portable program might be required to handle data written by a system using a different byte order. Less frequently today, you might find that even the layout of the bits in a `float` differs between systems. In general, this problem is often best solved by deferring to a library implementing a standard such as [XDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) (defined by [RFC 4506](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4506.txt)) that was designed to deal with binary portability.